# Replace word in file - UNIX command

Tags: command-line, unix

How can I replace 'word' on my file for a counter:

```
{"word":"resolucion","count":40723},{"word":"general","count":20976},
{"word":"","count":13334},{"word":"publica","count":12379},
{"word":"direccion","count":11958},{"word":"secretaria","count":9907},
{"word":"al","count":9324},{"word":"orden","count":8604},
{"word":"anuncia","count":8589},{"word":"concurso","count":6953},
{"word":"diciembre","count":6893},{"word":"adjudicacion","count":6762},
{"word":"estado","count":6154},{"word":"procedimiento","count":5694},
{"word":"julio","count":5598},{"word":"marzo","count":5440},
{"word":"-","count":5437},{"word":"convocatoria","count":5319},
{"word":"ayuntamiento","count":5259},{"word":"publico","count":5203},
{"word":"junio","count":4995},{"word":"convenio","count":4925},
{"word":"real","count":4916},{"word":"febrero","count":4896},
{"word":"proyecto","count":4826},{"word":"abierto","count":4782},
```

For example:

```
{"0":"resolucion","count":40723},{"1":"general","count":20976},
{"2":"","count":13334}, {"3":"publica","count":12379},
{"4":"direccion","count":11958},{"5":"secretaria","count":9907},
{"6":"al","count":9324},{"7":"orden","count":8604},
{"8":"anuncia","count":8589},
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution with our `grep` and `sed` friends. This is fine for small files, otherwise a `perl` (or `awk`?) solution will be much more performant.
This is `bash` syntax:

```
i=1
maxnum=$(grep -o '\<word\>' datafile | wc -l)
while (( i <= maxnum )); do
  sed -i "s/word/$i/" datafile
  (( i++ ))
done
```

`grep -o` counts the total number of *word* in `datafile`. This is from [Glenn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593376/2037712).
The only trick here is that `sed` isn't working globally, so replacing only the first matching string. That's why this code is so slow, as it invokes `sed` *maxnum* times on the whole datafile.

Be aware, that `sed -i` changes your original datafile, so make a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a JSON file, you can use some scripting language to modify it. For example, if you have NodeJS installed, you can run the following program:

```
var data = require('./data.json')

console.log(data)

data.forEach(function (obj, idx) { obj[idx] = obj['word']; delete obj.word; });

console.log(data)
```

I assume the file is named 'data.json' and that it's valid JSON syntax (yours isn't quite so: you're missing the wrapping `[` `]`and you have a spurious `,` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty fast.

```
perl -0 -ne 's/"word"/q{"} . $x++ . q{"}/ge; print;' INFILE > OUTFILE
```